# PHP with freebase /location/contains

Tags: php, html, arrays, json, freebase

I have this php file that gets the points (id,name,geolocation) of london.The problem is that I get the correct results as a json format but when i decode it and trying to get to contains array of results I get an error.How i can get the data from '/location/location/contains' attribute?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>search</title>
</head>

<body>
 <?php
 function freebasequery ($fid){
 $query = array(array('id' => $fid, '/location/location/contains'=>array(array('id'=>NULL,'name' => NULL,'/location/location/geolocation' =>array(array('/location/geocode/longitude' =>NULL,'/location/geocode/latitude' => NULL))))));
$query_envelope = array('query' => $query);
$service_url = 'http://api.freebase.com/api/service/mqlread';
$url = $service_url . '?query=' . urlencode(json_encode($query_envelope));
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $response;
 }
 $points=freebasequery('/en/london');
//echo $points;
 $results=json_decode($points)->result;
foreach($results as $poi){
    echo $poi->id;
    $contains="/location/location/contains";
    $poisarray=$poi->$contains;
    foreach($poisarray as $point){
        echo $point->id;
    }
}


 ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Can you show us the error that you're getting? Does it only happen with /en/london as the $fid or does it occur with any location ID?

Comment: i get a correct answer from freebase as json format e.g (with limit)

{ "code": "/api/status/ok", "result": [ { "/location/location/contains": [ { "/location/location/geolocation": [ { "/location/geocode/latitude": 51.533299999999997, "/location/geocode/longitude": -0.16669999999999999 } ], "id": "/en/london_borough_of_camden", "name": "London Borough of Camden" } ], "id": "/en/london" } ], "status": "200 OK", "transaction_id": "cache;cache03.p01.sjc1:8101;2011-12-27T17:04:01Z;0047" }

Comment: but when i make it as an array i cant get the id of the places in the "/location/location/contains"

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you can't get the ID? Does it give you a null pointer exception, is there some sort of error that gets displayed or it is just that your foreach loop doesn't print out any results?

Comment: doesn't give me anything.Just a blank page..(no errors in HTTP requests)

Comment: found the error it was on json_decode ( It requires to have a true) the solution is json_decode($points,true); and the data array I want is $results["result"][0]["/location/location/contains"];

Comment: Perhaps you could enter that solution as an answer and accept it so this question no longer shows up as "unanswered."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error it was on `json_decode` ( It requires to have a true) the solution is:

```
 json_decode($points,true);
```

and then I can access the data array I want like this:

```
$results["result"][0]["/location/location/contains"];
```

Comment: *it requires to have true*: well, that is not true. You worked around the problem, but it should have worked like you had it first, using `->` notation. The problem I see with your original code is a spelling mistake in the variable name *$poisarray*.